# Re-enter only certain values in html form

Tags: php, html

I am making an html form where I am taking certain inputs from user which include name, photos, and other details. I am also validating the fields (e.g. checking that a selected file entered is an image).

The problem is whenever the user select a file with the wrong type, it is checked only after the submit button is clicked!

I do not want the user to enter all the details of the form again -- only the field(s) he or she entered incorrectly should be required.

---

This is what I have tried:

```
<form action="abc.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="detail" value=<?php echo $_POST['detail']; ?> >
```

But it produces this error:

> Undefined variable : detail

I even tried:

```
<input type="text" name ="detail" value="<?php if($_POST['detail'])
                                                 $test=$_POST['detail'];
                                               else $test='';
                                               echo $test; ?>">
```

Comment: Replace $_POST by $_SESSION, and, in the script that handles the submitted form data, store the valid data in $_SESSION variables.

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit']) )
  header ('location:abc.php');
?>

<strong>Test Form</strong>
<form action="abc.php" method"post">
<input type="text" name="details" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['details']))echo $_SESSION['details'];
else echo 'junk' ; ?>" >
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>`   it shows "junk"

Comment: The "session" variables must be created in "abc.php", then you "header" back to the page that contains the form. "xyz.php" contains the form, when the form is submitted it jumps to "abc.php", here $_POST is converted in $_SESSION, then you call "header" to jump back to "xyz.php".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Javascript is used for validation of forms on the client side. So that you can stop the submission before posting the data(Before pressing Submit button)

It is the best practice because with that you avoid unnecessary server calls.

Please follow tutorial on the link given below to achieve your task:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/

Comment: ***Always*** validate server-side. Client-side validation is easily bypassed.

Answer (score 1):

Use php isset in order to check if the post variable is there or not in a ternary comparison:

```
<input type="text" name="detail" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['detail']) ? $_POST['detail'] : ''; ?>" />
```

Comment: No it didn't work ..i dont know why it keeps printing the false condition i.e. ' '

Comment: Add your full code please. I believe you are not submitting the form to the same script where you are showing it.

Answer (score -1):

use like following

```
<form action="abc.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="detail" value=<?php if(isset($_POST['detail'])){ echo $_POST['detail']; } ?> >
```

so every time when your form will load. then in value we need to check first if $_POST["detail"] is set ? then only we should print it. 
so by using isset() you can avoid such errors.